# Datatable angular4 with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

Error in **Datatable** and **angular 4** with **firebase**

I think the error in **| async**  because it is **not a JSON object**

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items | async; let i = index">
   <th scope="row">{{i}}</th>
   <th>{{item.$key}}</th>
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td>{{item.mobile}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Component.ts**

```
listOfUsers(page) {
this.items = <FirebaseListObservable<any>> this.af.list('/user', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'name'
  }
}).map((user)=>{
  return user.map(user_data=>{
    user_data.name;
    user_data.mobile;
    return user_data;
  })
})
}
```

how can i solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this link:

https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable